# Logstash removing the filters from API url

Tags: logstash

I am trying to deploy whole ELK stack , which I have successfully done , with Kibana Dashboards showing the performance of each API URL but some of the URL contains the filters [www.example.com/product/:Productid](http://www.example.com/product/:Productid)

eg

- [www.example.com/product/100](http://www.example.com/product/100)
- [www.example.com/product/200](http://www.example.com/product/200)
  ....etc

I want to show the top 5 worst performing URLs so developer can work toward improving the response time. Ideally the above URLs should be treated as same but since the it contains the ProductId it is treated as different URLs

I need help in removing such URL filters(ProductId) with simple Logic something like if the URLs contains numbers after the last "/" remove all characters post last "/" in the API URL and than push to Elasticsearch. So
post applying the logic the output for above two URLs should be same.

- [www.example.com/product/](http://www.example.com/product/)

Would appreciate any help

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mutate filter with the [gsub option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub).

If your urls are in a field called `url`, you'd put something like this in the filter section of your logstash configuration:

```
 mutate {
    gsub => [
      "url", "[^/]+$", ""
    ]
  }
```